# MySQL average two level agregation

Tags: mysql, group-by, average

Suppose I have a table with four fields in MySQL (id, week, day, value). The id field is an identifier for a device that takes several values per day.

What I want is calculate an average of value in a week-daily basis. The result will be other table with three fields (id, week, average_week_day_value), where the average value is not the average in a week basis, but in a week-daily basis. I mean: first we calculate the day-average, and after that, the week-day-average as an average of days-average-values per week.

Now, I implement that in two steps, with an intermediate table (id, week, day, average-day-value). After I have the intermediate table it's easy to calculate final table: (id, week, average_week_day_value)

Can I do that in a single step?

**EDIT**

First step query:

```
INSERT INTO daily (id,week,day,average)
   SELECT id, week, day, avg(value)
   FROM table_values
   GROUP BY day
```

Second step query:

```
INSERT INTO weekly (id,week,avg)
    SELECT id,week,avg(average)
    FROM daily
    GROUP BY week
```

Comment: Where's your query???  How do you expect for help if don't give the info???

Comment: For the info given, my answer is aggregate it, then aggregate it again.

Comment: I wrote a sample query. The problem is a little bit more complicated because the number of fields, but this is the essence.

Comment: I suggest you write a proper query.  Include all non-aggregated columns in your `GROUP BY`.  Both of your queries don't even run in other dbms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put your first query in a subquery.

```
SELECT week, AVG(day_avg)
FROM (
    SELECT week, day, AVG(value) AS day_avg
    FROM table_values
    GROUP BY week, day
) d
GROUP BY week
```